# Composer with PSR-4 autoloading: classes from namespace not loading

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I have the follow project structure:

```
- root
|- src <- Application specifc source
  |- [...]
|- tests
  |- [...]
|- Vendor
  |- myusername <- shared packages for all projects
    |- src
      |- MyNamespace
        |- File.php
  |- autoload.php
  |- test.php
|- composer.json
```

`composer.json` already have a PSR-4 entry:

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
         "MyNamespace\\":"myusername/src"
     }
}
```

`/Vendor/test.php`

```
<?php
require 'autoload.php';

$file = new MyNamespace\File();
echo $file->isDone();
```

`Vendor/myusername/src/MyNamespace/File.php`

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;

class File
{
    public function isDone()
    {
        return 'Done!';
    }
}
```

But I always get fatal error `Fatal error: Class 'MyNamespace\File' not found in [...]`

Are the composer settings or file structure correct? What I can do?

**EDIT 1:**

I can load external vendors fine

Comment: Have you tried putting your directory with sources outside of Vendor? I usually have project structure like sth/src/MyNamespace/... and sth/Vendor/...

Comment: This is a shared vendor for all of my projects, not the project source, so, it is in Vendor directory.

Comment: @mareckmareck I have updated the project structure to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong with your code.

**You are using PSR-4 wrong.**

They removed the need to embed the namespace in your folders, making a cleaner footprint in your project folder.

```
PSR-0
vendor/<VendorName>/<ProjectName>/src/<NamespaceVendor>/<NamespaceProject>/File.php

PSR-4 (See that they removed the namespaces folders? Because you already reference that in composer.json
vendor/<VendorName>/<ProjectName>/src/File.php
```

So in your case it would be:

```
Vendor/myusername/src/File.php
```

**Your composer.json is invalid**

```
         "MyNamespace\\":"myusername/src"
```

Doesn't include the full path to the directory with your project's code. It should be like this:

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
         "MyNamespace\\": "Vendor/myusername/src"
     }
}
```

but the best way to store your files would be **outside the `vendor` directory**, as that is used by automatically downloaded libraries, instead choose a different "development" directory:

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
         "MyUsername\\MyProject\\": "src/myusername/myproject/src"
     }
}
```

Thanks to Sven in the comments.

Comment: Hey! I have made confusion with PSR-0 and 4, I'm wrong with my namespaces :c

Comment: A few seconds before your reply I have solved structuring the project correctly, and verifying that composer will find files from root directory instead of vendor directory. All fine now (:

Comment: Never ever define the autoloading in the main `composer.json` with a path that goes into `vendor`. Assuming that Composer will manage the packages, it would be the task of that specific package to declare the autoloading for itself. Which would be a different root path then, without any `vendor/myusername/myproject` prefix.